# PayPal Client-Side REST: dynamic prices

Tags: javascript, php, rest, paypal

I am using PayPal Client-Side REST for my project. I have different products each with different prices. I have a textbox that contains the total price of all products in cart. but when I try to get the value of that textbox I am getting an error with paypal API. below is my code:

```
<input type="number" id="total_amount">
<div id="paypal-button-container" class="text-right"></div>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    var amt =  $('#total_amount').val();
    paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
        sandbox:    '<sandbox_api_ey>',
        production: '<insert production client id>'
    },

    payment: function(data, actions) {
        var amt = $('#total_amount').val();
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: amt, currency: 'JPY' }
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            window.alert('Payment Complete!');
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

as you can see from my code, I stored the amount in a variable `var amt = $('#total_amount').val();` then use that variable inside the json.

My problem is I am getting this error in the console and paypal window won't open.
[image]

it is pointing to currency, but I am pretty sure that it is correct, whenever I hard coded the amount it functions properly.

Comment: Do you hardcode it as a number or a string ?

Comment: i hardcoded it as a string

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
payment: function (data, actions) {

var x = document.getElementById("total_amount");
var currentVal = x.value;

console.log(currentVal);
return actions.payment.create({
  transactions: [{
    amount: {
      total: currentVal,
      currency: 'JPY'
    }
  }]
});
}
```

Also, make sure to test on an HTTPS environment

See full working snippet here

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/vwas4cqj/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0"></iframe>
```